# Linked Reports in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I am new to power bi and  I am working on a project that has two reports.
Report 1 has date,store and count.
Report 2 has department and count . (per store and date as selected in report 1)
The heierarchy is store -> department. i.e each store has multiple departments.
I want to link these 2 reports i.e when i click on  count of store x for date y in report 1 it should take me to report 2 by passing store and date as parameters.
Is there any way to create Linked reports by passing parameters in power bi as we do in ssrs?

Comment: Why don't you add all tables into 1 data model, create your relationships there, so you don't have to worry about linking the reports. You can just filter for whatever you are interested in, in one report.

Comment: @StelioK
They are from the same transaction table. The count is for the customers. A customer can go and shop from different departments in a store. So at store level for customer count I Just cannot add all the department customer counts . As it will be projected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use linkCube in Olap(SSAS). You have two cubes with severall measurse, you should create linkCube inside another cube, then you can use the information of both cubes in a Power BI report.